# Can a int16_t to int conversation result in implementation-defined behavior?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, c99, language-lawyer

In **section 7.18.1.1** paragraph 1 of the C99 standard:

> The typedef name **`intN_t`** designates a signed integer type with width *N*, no padding
>   bits, and a two’s complement representation.

According to the C99 standard, exact-width signed integer types are required to have a *two's complement* representation. This means, for example, `int8_t` has a minimum value of `-128` as opposed to the *one's complement* minimum value of `-127`.

**Section 6.2.6.2** paragraph 2 allows the implementation to decide whether to interpret a sign bit as *sign and magnitude*, *two's complement*, or *one's complement*:

> If the sign bit is one, the value shall be
>   modified in one of the following ways:
>   — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (*sign and magnitude*);
>   — the sign bit has the value -(2<sup>N</sup>) (*two’s complement*);
>   — the sign bit has the value -(2<sup>N</sup> - 1) (*ones’ complement*).

The distinct between the methods is important because the minimum value of an integer in *two's complement* (`-128`) can be outside the range of values representable in *ones' complement* (`-127` to `127`).

Suppose an implementation defines the `int` types as having `ones' complement` representation, while the `int16_t` type has `two's complement` representation as guaranteed by the C99 standard.

```
int16_t foo = -32768;
int bar = foo;
```

In this case, would the conversion from `int16_t` to `int` cause *implementation-defined behavior* since the value held by `foo` is outside the range of values representable by `bar`?

Comment: It is very unlikely for an implementation to have `int16_t` and `int` with one's complement signed representation. It is the rationale for C  to mark these exact-width integer types as optional.

Comment: It makes me wonder why the exact-width signed integer types have this *two's complement* explicit requirement rather than leaving it up to the implementation as the basic signed integer types do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Specifically, the conversion would yield an implementation-defined result. (For any value other than `-32768`, the result and the behavior would be well defined.) Or the conversion could raise an implementation-defined signal, but I don't know of any implementations that do that.

Reference for the conversion rules: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.3p3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

This can only happen if:

- `int` is 16-bits (more precisely, has 15 value bits, 1 sign bit, and 0 or more padding bits)
- `int` uses one's-complement or sign-and magnitude
- The implementation also supports two's-complement (otherwise it just won't define `int16_t`).

I'd be surprised to see an implementation that meets these criteria. It would have to support both two's-complement and either one's complement or sign-and-magnitude, and it would have to chose one of the latter for type `int`. (Perhaps a non-two's-complement implementation might support two's-complement in software, just for the sake of being able to define `int16_t`.)

If you're concerned about this possibility, you might consider adding this to one of your header files:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if !defined(INT16_MIN)
#error "int16_t is not defined"
#elif INT_MIN > INT16_MIN
#error "Sorry, I just can't cope with this weird implementation"
#endif
```

The `#error`s are not likely to trigger on any sane real-world implementation.

Comment: Also, since implementing `int16_t` is optional, you should also test to see if `INT16_MIN` is defined.

Comment: @jxh Does the C99 standard require that `INT16_MIN` is defined if `int16_t` is also defined?

Comment: From C.99 §7.18 ¶4: For each type described herein that the implementation provides, `<stdint.h>` shall
declare that `typedef` name and define the associated macros. Conversely, for each type
described herein that the implementation does not provide, `<stdint.h>` shall not
declare that `typedef` name **nor shall it define the associated macros.**

Comment: Isn't the check for `INT16_MIN` unnecessary in this particular case since attempting to use the `int16_t` will itself cause a compiler error if not defined?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Yes, but this gives a better diagnostic, and shows the programmer anticipates it. You could in theory use this to provide alternative code for the aberrant platform.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Using `#error` (a) catches the error as early as possible, (b) lets me control the error message that appears, and (c) guarantees that the code will actually fail to compile. Diagnostics for syntax errors and constraint violations can be mere warnings, with the compilation continuing (language extensions can be implemented this way); only `#error` guarantees failure.

Comment: Are two's-complement implementations required to yield defined behavior with -32768, or could a compiler legitimately assume that if x is negative, -x will be positive?

Comment: @supercat: When the standard talks about two's-complement, it's referring only to the way signed integers are represented. It doesn't impose any requirements on overflow behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: On two's-complement machines, from a hardware perspective, -16384 + -16384 won't "overflow" in the usual sense.  The question would be whether use of two's-complement implies that INT_MIN must be -32768, or whether an implementation could say that INT_MIN is -32767 and treat any calculation which would yield -32768 as Undefined Behavior, thus potentially avoiding some kinds of special-case code to deal with that value.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, a compiler could define `INT_MIN == -32767` and `INT_MAX == +32767`, and treat `INT_MIN-1` as a trap representation. Evaluating `-16384 + -16384` would then have undefined behavior. The behavior could differ depending on whether the computation is done at compile time or at run time. And `-16384 + -16384` would not be a constant expression, since it would violate the constraint in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.6p4: "Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type."