# Program with two different binary representations for signed integers

Tags: c, language-lawyer

From standard, regarding fixed-width data types:

> [7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types] The typedef name intN_t
>   designates a signed integer type with width N , no padding bits, and a
>   **two's complement representation**

Also from the standard [6.2.6.2 Integer types] a number can be represented by **sign-and-magnitude, 1's complement or 2's complement**.

So according to standard we can have a program with `int32_t` in 2's complement representation, and `int` with, let's say 1's complement representation. Now, what will happen if we compare them? or perform arithmetics with both of them? integer promotion rules will take place but how will the compiler (who does not know the `int` binary representation of the machine) compose the result given two different representations?

Comment: I don't take that as saying that the two can exist in a program. Rather, I'd interpret that as saying that the stdint ones don't exist on sign-and-magnitude representation.

Comment: How could the compiler not know the binary representation of `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a int16\_t to int conversation result in implementation-defined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112109/can-a-int16-t-to-int-conversation-result-in-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: In that case, the compiler would have to know both formats, and generate whatever intermediate code was required to work between them.   It isn’t incredibly different from supporting floats on a machine with no floating point hardware (eg. z80, 6809, 68000).   Standards are not intended to hold up to such a level of scrutiny; they are guidelines.

Comment: @melpomene does the compiler must know the `int` representation in a specific  machine in order to construct a conforming program? I don't think so, but I'm not 100% certain

Comment: 1s', not 1's...

Comment: @user2162550: It is not technically necessary for a compiler to know what representation a machine uses for integers in order to be part of a conforming C implementation. It could provide C semantics for `int` by emulating them. In other words, it could implement `int` by manipulating bits itself instead of by using machine instructions such as `add` or `neg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int32_t` is not guaranteed to exist on a given platform.  Presumably, if you had a non twos-complement architecture, `int32_t` would not be defined.

From 7.20.1.1 of the standard describing exact-width integers:

> The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> The  typedef  name uintN_t designates  an  unsigned  integer  type  with  width N and  no padding  bits.  Thus, uint24_t denotes  such  an  unsigned  integer  type  with  a  width  of
>   exactly 24 bits.
>
> **These types are optional.** However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

If, for whatever reason, a machine with sign-and-magnitude or ones-complement architecture was to be created and a compiler adapted for it, and that compiler decided it would choose to create the option exact-width types, the compiler writer would find themselves having to convert the exact-width integers to native integral types whenever they wanted to perform arithmetic on them and then convert back to store in the variable.  It could be particularly troublesome since two's complement can represent a wider range of values than sign-and-magnitude and one's complement.

tl;dr: A compiler could *possibly* make an implementation of exact-width integers on a platform that is not two's complement, but nobody would actually bother to do so because they're optional and the implementation would be rather inefficient.

Comment: Honest question: Are you 100% sure about this? I was under the impression that C99 requires the compiler to define/support `int{8,16,32}_t` and `uint{8,16,32}_t` in `<stdint.h>`. EDIT: thank you for reference/clarification

Comment: @MortenJensen Positive.  See my edit.  The `int_fastN_t` and `int_leastN_t` types are required, but not the exact-width types.  If you had an architecture where `CHAR_BIT = 9`, you wouldn't have any native 8,16,32,64 bit types, but rather 9,18,36,and 72 bit types.  Worth noting that the least/fast types that *are* required don't come with the constraint that they must be two's complement.

Comment: A C99 or C11 compiler could theoretically exist for a platform that isn't two's-complement, but any almost any realistically-imaginable practical platform that could efficiently support `uint_least64_t` would be able to efficiently support two's-complement math.  Making two's-complement optional would make sense if and only if `uint_least64_t` and `unsigned long long` were likewise.

Answer (score 2):

Even if a compiler would use two different ways of representing integers, the compiler would still know how to compare them or how to use them in calculations.
This is guaranteed by the compiler having to obey the corresponding other parts of the standard, i.e. it is defined how the resulting behaviour of a comparison or a calculation should be.

The C standard leaves many implementation details open, in order to allow creation of efficient compilers. The resulting behaviour however is defined and the implementation details, which are of course know to the compiler, cannot change that. Two different integer representations would usually result in a more complex method to use them together, i.e. it probably is avoided by compiler suppliers.